# Redux-form semantic UI with AsyncValidation

Tags: redux-form, semantic-ui-react

**Need help**

I followed this example http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/submitValidation/
and http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/asyncValidation/

I use Semanitic-UI & made a loading state Redux-form component as code below:

Loading state of the semantic Input is:

You could find it [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input#input-example-loading)

```
...
const ReduxFormInput = ({ input, label, placeholder, checkboxLabel, type, meta: { asyncValidate, touched, error } }) => {
  const errorMessage = (<div style={{ color: '#E20000', paddingTop: '.3rem', fontSize: '12px' }} >
    <Icon name="warning" />
    {error}
  </div>);

  return (
    <div>
      <Label>{label}</Label>
      <Input  // styled semantic-ui-react Input 
        {...input}
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        error={error ? true : null}
        loading={asyncValidate ? true : undefined} // load loading state when submitting 
        icon={asyncValidate ? 'user' : undefined} // load icon state when submitting
      />
      {touched && error && errorMessage}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReduxFormInput;
```

The form work perfectly instead of Async Loading state within semantic-ui component not works.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my answer

```
const ReduxFormInput = ({ input, label, placeholder, checkboxLabel, type, meta: { submitting, asyncValidate, touched, error } }) => ...

<Input
  {...input}
  type={type}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  error={error ? true : null}
  loading={submitting|| asyncValidate ? true : undefined} // ---> semantic-ui-react loading prop, state when submitting 
  icon={submitting|| asyncValidate ? 'user' : undefined} // ---> semantic-ui-react icon prop, load icon when submitting
/>
```